# CloudBoost: undefined columns in CloudObject

Tags: javascript, undefined, cloudboost

I'm new to Cloudboost, and 
I was just wondering about one thing :

Let's say I have 2 tables : one named Question'' and one named 'Answer'.

'Question' has a column named answers wich contains a list of 'Answer'.

Why can't I read any of the 'Answer' column in a 'Question' element after getting it like that?

```
var query = new CB.CloudQuery('Question');
    query.find({
        success: function (list) {
            $scope.myQuestions = list;
            console.log($scope.myQuestions);

        }, error: function (error) {
            });
        }
    });
```

When I debug, i can see most columns are "undefined" and the columns I created are not shown... Do I have to load every 'Answer' of the list thanks to their ID ? (because the only column not undefined is the ID).

Am I missing something ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include all the related objects by,

`query.include('columnName')`

before you do query.find(). Let me know if this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That's exactly what I was looking for ;)